# Extend python with C, return numpy array gives garbage

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, numpy, wrapper

I am wrapping a C file so I can use it in python. The output of the C function is an array of doubles. I want this to be a numpy array in python. I get garbage. Here's an example that generates the error.

First, the C file (focus on the last function definition, everything else should be OK):

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static char module_docstring[] =
    "docstring";

static char error_docstring[] =
        "generate the error";

static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
        {"error", _aux_error, METH_VARARGS, error_docstring},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_tmp(void) {

    PyObject *m = Py_InitModule3("_tmp", module_methods, module_docstring);
    if (m == NULL)
        return;

    /* Load `numpy` functionality. */
    import_array();
}

static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self ,PyObject *args) {

    double vector[2] = {1.0 , 2.0};

    npy_intp dims[1] = { 2 };

    PyObject *ret  = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, (int)NPY_FLOAT , vector );
    return ret;
}
```

Compilation goes OK (from what I understand - I used a python script that compiles everything).

In python, I run the following script to test my new module:

```
try:
    import _tmp
    res = _tmp.error()
    print(res)
except:
    print("fail")
```

The result I see on the screen is garbage. I tried substituting `(int)NPY_FLOAT` with `(int)NPY_FLOAT32, (int)NPY_FLOAT64, (int)NPY_DOUBLE` and I still get garbage.
I am using python2.7.

Thanks!!!

**EDIT**: following the answer below, I changed the last function to:

```
static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {


    double *vector = calloc(2, sizeof(double));
    vector[0] = 1.0;
    vector[1] = 2.0;


    npy_intp *dims = calloc(1 , sizeof(npy_intp));
    dims[1] = 2;


    PyObject *ret  = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, (int)NPY_FLOAT , &vector );
    return ret;
}
```

Now python shows an empty array.

Comment: The call in you edit should be `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, vector)`. Does it not work like that either?

Comment: `dims[1] = 2` is an indexing error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self) {
```

to this:

```
static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
```

Python will pass the `args` argument, even if you don't define your function with it.

There's still a fundamental problem with your code.  You have created a numpy array using an array, `vector`, that is on the stack.  When `_aux_error` returns, that memory is reclaimed and might be reused.

You could create the array using `PyArray_SimpleNew()` to allocate the numpy array, and then copy `vector` to the array's data:

```
static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    double vector[2] = {1.0 , 2.0};
    npy_intp dims[1] = {2};

    PyObject *ret = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
    memcpy(PyArray_DATA(ret), vector, sizeof(vector));
    return ret;
}
```

Note that I changed the type to `NPY_DOUBLE`; `NPY_FLOAT` is the 32 bit floating point type.

---

In a comment, you asked about dynamically allocating the memory in `_aux_error`.  Here's a variation of the example that might be useful.  The length of the array is still hardcoded in `dims`, so it isn't completely general, but it might be enough to address the question from the comments.

```
static PyObject *_aux_error(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    double *vector;
    npy_intp dims[1] = {5};
    npy_intp k;

    PyObject *ret = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
    vector = (double *) PyArray_DATA(ret);
    /*
     *  NOTE: Treating PyArray_DATA(ret) as if it were a contiguous one-dimensional C
     *  array is safe, because we just created it with PyArray_SimpleNew, so we know
     *  that it is, in fact, a one-dimensional contiguous array.
     */
    for (k = 0; k < dims[0]; ++k) {
        vector[k] = 1.0 + k;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but this does not help. Shouldn't the example become simpler by removing the *args and not giving the function any variable?

Comment: No--the python interpreter has no idea that you have defined `_aux_error` with a nonstandard signature.  It will be called with the two C arguments.

Comment: Note that I updated my answer with a comment about a fundamental problem with your example.

Comment: Using your advice I tried to change the way arrays are created. I use `calloc`. Is this the right way to do it? I am still getting garbage (not to mention the fact that I'll have to deallocate that memory from within python somehow).

Comment: The dimensions are copied by the array constructor, but the array  data isn't.

Comment: Thank you so much! Last thing, if you may: in my real program I want to dynamically allocate memory for the array vector. Should I free that memory after using memcpy? Again, thank you for your time.

Comment: If in `_aux_error` you have something like `vector = malloc(...);`, then you fill `vector` with some computed values, and then call `PyObject *ret = PyArray_SimpleNew(...); memcpy(PyArray_DATA(ret), vector, sizeof(vector));`, then yes, you should free `vector` before you return.  But if you know the length of the array, you could call `PyObject *ret = PyArray_SimpleNew(...)`, and then use `double *vector = PyArray_DATA(ret)`, and fill in `vector`.  Then you wouldn't need to malloc any memory--since `PyArray_SimpleNew` did that for you--and you wouldn't free `vector`.

Comment: See the latest addition to my answer for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my full solution, for your amusement. Copy, paste and modify. Obviously the problem I was faced with is a bit more complicated than the question above. I used some of 
[Dan Foreman Mackay's online code](http://dan.iel.fm/posts/python-c-extensions/).

The goal of my code is to return a covariance vector (whatever that is). I have a C file  named `aux.c` that returns a newly allocated array:

```
#include "aux.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double *covVec(double *X, double *x, int nvecs, int veclen) {


    double r = 1.3;
    double d = 1.0;

    double result;
    double dist;
    int n;

    double *k;
    k = malloc(nvecs * sizeof(double));

    int row;
    for( row = 0 ; row < nvecs ; row++) {

        result = 0.0;
        for (n = 0; n < veclen; n++) {
                dist = x[n] - X[row*veclen + n];
                result += dist * dist;
        }

        result = d*exp(  -result/(2.0*r*r)  );
        k[row] = result;
    }
    return k;
}
```

Then, I need a very short header file named `aux.h`:

```
double *covVec(double *X, double *x, int nvecs, int veclen);
```

To wrap this to python I have `_aux.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include "aux.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static char module_docstring[] =
    "This module provides an interface for calculating covariance using C.";

static char cov_vec_docstring[] =
    "Calculate the covariances between a vector and a list of vectors.";

static PyObject *_aux_covVec(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);

static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
        {"cov_vec", _aux_covVec, METH_VARARGS, cov_vec_docstring},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC init_aux(void) {

    PyObject *m = Py_InitModule3("_aux", module_methods, module_docstring);
    if (m == NULL)
        return;

    /* Load `numpy` functionality. */
    import_array();
}


static PyObject *_aux_covVec(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *X_obj, *x_obj;

    /* Parse the input tuple */
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "OO", &X_obj, &x_obj ))
        return NULL;

    /* Interpret the input objects as numpy arrays. */
    PyObject *X_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(X_obj, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);
    PyObject *x_array = PyArray_FROM_OTF(x_obj, NPY_DOUBLE, NPY_IN_ARRAY);


    /* If that didn't work, throw an exception. */
    if (X_array == NULL || x_array == NULL ) {
        Py_XDECREF(X_array);
        Py_XDECREF(x_array);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* What are the dimensions? */
    int nvecs  = (int)PyArray_DIM(X_array, 0);
    int veclen = (int)PyArray_DIM(X_array, 1);
    int xlen   = (int)PyArray_DIM(x_array, 0);

    /* Get pointers to the data as C-types. */
    double *X    = (double*)PyArray_DATA(X_array);
    double *x    = (double*)PyArray_DATA(x_array);


    /* Call the external C function to compute the covariance. */
    double *k = covVec(X, x, nvecs, veclen);



    if ( veclen !=  xlen ) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                                "Dimensions don't match!!");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Clean up. */
    Py_DECREF(X_array);
    Py_DECREF(x_array);

    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < nvecs ; i++) {
        printf("k[%d]   = %f\n",i,k[i]);
        if (k[i] < 0.0) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeError,
                        "Covariance should be positive but it isn't.");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    npy_intp dims[1] = {nvecs};

    PyObject *ret = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
    memcpy(PyArray_DATA(ret), k, nvecs*sizeof(double));
    free(k);

    return ret;
}
```

I have a python file called `setup_cov.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
import numpy.distutils.misc_util

setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension("_aux", ["_aux.c", "aux.c"])],
    include_dirs=numpy.distutils.misc_util.get_numpy_include_dirs(),
)
```

I compile from command line using `python2.7 setup_cov.py build_ext --inplace`.
Then I run the following python test file:

```
import numpy as np
import _aux as a

nvecs  = 6
veclen = 9
X= []
for _ in range(nvecs):
    X.append(np.random.normal(size= veclen))
X = np.asarray(X)

x = np.random.normal(size=veclen)
k = a.cov_vec(X,x)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 2):

Warren's solution seems to be working, although freeing the C array memory block results in a error on compilation for me. I got the memcopy trick to work in the minimalistic function below (copying a 1D C array to numpy via the pointer), which, for simplicity, does not take any arguments, and should give the reader a good idea how to apply this to C arrays instead of vectors:

```
static PyObject *_cmod_test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
    {
    double f[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    int d[1] = {5};
    PyObject *c = PyArray_FromDims(1,d,NPY_DOUBLE);
    memcpy(PyArray_DATA(c), f, 5*sizeof(double));
    return c;    
    };
```

The launch.py script is simple

```
import _cmod
_cmod.test()
```

Don't forget to declare the functions

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
static PyObject *_cmod_test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args);
```

Any suggestions for the use with PyArray_SimpleNewFromData (whilst avoiding the memory leak pittfall)? Perhaps something similar to the broken code below.

```
static PyObject *_cmod_test(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
    {
    double f[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
    npy_intp dims[1] = {5};
    PyObject *c = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE ,f);
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(c, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);
    return c;
    };
```

I also recommend Dan Foreman Mackay's blog on the python C API.